# Can't install Distribution provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'd like to submit an app to the AppStore (my first app !).
I've already tested the application in my device (so I already have a development provisioning profile) but I'm not able to install a Distribution provisioning profile in Xcode.
I've followed the procedure (I don't know how many times) but when I try to add the provisioning profile through the Organizer I have following problems:

- if I double click on the file nothing happens
- if I click Add, the file is not selectable (grey)
- if I drag and drop from Finder I see the following message: 1 profile
  cannot be installed on "iPhone of Corrado". "iPhone of Corrado" is not included  in this profile.

What does it means ?
If I go in the Development Center\Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles\Provisioning Profiles\Distribution and edit the profile, there is no devices and there is no way to add any (while in the Development provisioning profile I see all my devices).
What I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks, Corrado

Comment: You do not need to install the distribution profile to your device. If you use Xcode 5, try checking Preferences → Accounts → <your account> → View Details... Most likely the profile has already been added to your Xcode when you double-clicked it.

Comment: I always find the following link very helpful when it's time to submit my apps : [apple developer submit your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know which Xcode you are using, but supposing you are using Xcode-5, i suggest you use the automatic provisioning profile sync feature.

Just go to Xcode>Preferences and select the Accounts tab.

If you don't have any Apple IDs account signed just click on the '+' button on the bottom left and select 'Add Apple ID...', put the id and password that you use to log on the apple developer.

After that just click on the 'View Details...' button on the bottom right, and your signing identities and provisioning profiles should appear there. If they don't, just click on the bottom left refresh button.

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent the last 12 hours trying to figure out why my OSX App wasn't code signing and the error was related to the provisioning profile containing 0 devices for my Mac.  After following the advice above, much head scratching, deleting and re-creating certificates, the following link provides the correct approach for Distribution provisioning

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Moving forward it seems that for Mac App Store Submission on OSX the correct code signing identity to use is **Mac Developer** and set the **Provisioning Profile** to Automatic.

You do need to restart Xcode during the Code Signing and Provisioning reset, but it does work.