# "The private key for [App Name] is not installed on this mac"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, certificate, organizer

I'm trying to validate my app in Xcode. However, I get this error:

[image]

I have tried revoking my distribution certificate and making a new one. Nothing seems to work at all.

Here is my Keychain Access screen:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what to do.

EDIT: I revoked every single one of my certificates and provisioning profiles and started from scratch. I made a new development certificate and a new distribution certificate. I then made a new development provisioning profile, and a new distribution provisioning profile.

I added both certificates to Keychain Access, and added the development provisioning profile to Xcode. Everything is okay. I then add the distribution provisioning profile, and once again, I get this error:

[image]

Why is it so hard to do this?!? I need help please!

Comment: I agree, nothing should be this hard. Struggling with this now. Will not choose to develop on apple again after this app is published. Android only.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. Sometimes duplicate profile make this problem. There are many other reason for this. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590356/xcode-the-private-key-for-is-not-installed-on-this-mac-distributing).

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: This is getting ridiculous now.. Check my edit please.

Comment: These problems sucks. I face similar problem twice but solved in two different way. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798330/cant-install-distribution-provisioning-profile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be